# How can I debug keystore for Map View

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created a map. Then I generated an md5 and got an API key from Google. In my project, I followed all of the necessary steps. But the Map View still won't display.

Followed steps in project

1. I have choosen Google API Project
2. MapControl with MapAPI in xml
3. In the Manifest I have added internet permission and `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`

Does anyone know what might cause this issue or how to debug it?

Comment: Did you add the API key to your project?

Comment: yes i have my Api key which obtain from google

Comment: Okay. But did you actually add it to your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons why the Map View is not being displayed

a)  If you are developing with eclipse check if eclipse is pointing to the debug-keystore file. In eclipse Navigate to Windows > Preferences >Android > Build

The path of your default debug keystore should be like

```
  <Documents and Settings>\<user-name>\.android\debug.keystore
```

In case of linux look for the appropriate path.

Some people on SO also suggest pointing the path of the custom debug keystore to that of the default keystore

Moreover if your key is the problem the same must be displayed in logcat

b)  If you are sitting behind a corporate firewall you will have to pass your proxy options to your emulator

Under Debug configuration > Target scroll down to Additional Emulator Command Line Options and enter your proxy settings as

```
-http-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>
```