# MapView Not Loading Tiles Even With Correct Key

Tags: android, android-mapview

So I have generated my API key by getting my MD5 certificate fingerprint from my debug store using this command in the terminal...

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <my_debug.keystore_location> -storepass android -keypass android
```

This is generated fine and I then go online enter it into the text box, hit generate and get my api key which I then enter into my xml layout like so..

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="my_api_key/>
```

Then in my AndroidManifest.xml I have added the permission for internet before the Application tag and inside the applicate tag I have put the library reference.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My AVD is the correct api target as well as my project. The MapView is displaying but only with the grey tiles. I also have internet in the emulator as I checked using the browser.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Ok looking in my `LogCat` it says

> Couldn't get connection factory client

So I'm guessing thats what the problem is?
Prior to this appearing in the `LogCat` it also says

> Handling Network change notification:CONNECTED

Comment: have you created google-api Emulator ? if not then check it. Else export your project and run apk in8 your Device then check

Comment: Yes I have created a google api emulator

Comment: then run your application in your device.

Comment: Is there anything in your Logcat?

Comment: I know you should have done it..just confirming that did you put your api key in layout.xml ... at the line `android:apiKey="my_api_key` because as of now it is `my_api_key` it has to be something like `android:apiKey="0s7dGEMQ1i4rUWgKuKkfhUs2WFyXkhNSjPjyHag"`

Comment: I have just added some things under EDIT about LogCat

Comment: @DiscoS2 the LogCat message "Couldn't get connection factory client" is misleading, that is not a problem. It appears even when everything works fine. Please checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293631/how-can-i-debug-keystore-for-map-view/11293808#11293808 if the accepted answer there helps

Comment: @Anand nope that doesn't help. Everything there is correct

Comment: @DiscoS2 are you behind a corporate firewall ?

Comment: No I'm at home, no problems there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. Yet another ridiculously simple solution that I should have spotted. If you look at the code below which is taken from my original question, you may be able to spot the mistake.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.INTERNET"/>
```

Got it? `android.permissions.INTERNET` should be `android.permission.INTERNET`. That's right... SINGULAR.

After this, it still didn't work. However after deleting my debug.keystore and debug.keyset from my .android folder and then restarting eclipse and doing a fresh install to regenerate them, I then got a new API key and hey presto, it worked.

I hope this helps someone else and these **stupid** mistakes can be avoided.

I have also written a [walkthrough](http://discocode.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/android-the-goole-maps-api-9/) on how to get the Google Maps API working that should help you out.